# Merge objects dynamically - Object Property Name Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to merge objects together, or add new objects to existing objects.
I've already got it working as for merge using jQuery, but it's the name of the property that wont work dynamically.

The parameter `filters` is an object, such as `{test:123}`.

When invoking `filter({test:123});`, I want the `filter` function to dynamically add objects to a global object. (and of course can't use `push()` since its not an array)

```
this.filter = function(filters) {
  for (var key in filters) {
    $.extend( settings.filter, {key:filters[key]} );
  }
};
```

The problem is that "key" turns into "key" as the name of the property. When it should be "test" as the property name; I can not get the property name to be created dynamically.

The goal would be to allow the user to fire the function like this:

```
filter({test:123,test2:1321,test55:4})
```

and dynamically add objects to the global settings object without the user meddling with the object itself.

Comment: Why are you doing it that way instead of just `$.extend(settings.filter, filters)`?

Comment: ...the exact reason for the issue you describe is very simply that the object initializer syntax can't possibly know that you actually want to use the value of the `key` variable instead of an actual identifier named `key`. There are many questions on StackOverflow that address how to create an object with dynamic keys, but it's all beside the point since your approach isn't the way to do it in the first place.

Comment: @cookiemonster thank you. I dont know why I was trying to do that, I was thinking of arrays and usually in php I foreach or for loop them together, but $.extend( settings.filter, filters ); fixed the problem, makes it simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because key is not being interpreted as a variable when being directly set in the object.

```
$.extend( settings.filter, {key:filters[key]} );
```

Considering:

```
var keyName = "Test";
var badObj = { keyName: "Hello World" };
```

You would get undefined when calling `newObj.Test` because it is actually `newObj.keyName`.

In order to use a variable to create a property name, you need to use different syntax.

```
var keyName = "Test";
var newObj = {};
newObj[keyName] = "Hello World";
```

You could then reference and use `newObj.Test` to get "Hello World"

To fix the method you provided, you can adjust it to:

```
this.filter = function(filters) {
  for (var key in filters) {
   if (filters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var newObj = {};
      newObj[key] = filters[key];
      $.extend(settings.filter, newObj);
    }
  }
};
```

Keep in mind you can simplify this and just use the extend method. This would be better, unless you are looking to do your own filtering as the method name suggests.

```
this.filter = function(filters) {
    $.extend(settings.filter, filters);
};
```

[Demos](http://jsbin.com/penaq/1/)

Comment: Thank you. the simple way of just running extend,
$.extend(settings.filter, filters); worked perfectly. 
seems that I was trying to code like I'm doing php arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should create temp obj before extend :

```
this.filter = function(filters) {
  for (var key in filters) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = filters[key];
    $.extend( settings.filter, obj );
  }
};
```